# How can I optimize this query with 5 subqueries?

Tags: mysql, optimization

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.hours), 0) AS allotted_hours
   FROM tasks AS t
   WHERE t.projects_id = 8
     AND t.complete != 100
     AND t.name LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Placeholder%') AS allotted_hours_notcomplete_ongoing,

  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tl.hours), 0) AS hr
   FROM tasks AS t
   INNER JOIN tasklogs AS tl ON (tl.tasks_id = t.id)
   WHERE t.projects_id = 8
     AND t.complete != 100
     AND t.name LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Placeholder%') AS logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing,

  (SELECT (allotted_hours_notcomplete_ongoing - logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing) + logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing) AS difference_notcomplete_ongoing,

  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.hours), 0) AS hr
   FROM tasks AS t
   WHERE t.projects_id = 8
     AND t.complete != 100
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE 'Placeholder%') AS allotted_hours_notcomplete_regular,

  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(tl.hours), 0) AS hr
   FROM tasklogs AS tl
   INNER JOIN tasks AS t ON (t.id = tl.tasks_id
                             AND t.projects_id = 8
                             AND t.complete = 100)
   WHERE hourtypes_id IN (1,
                          2)) AS logged_hours_complete,

  (SELECT logged_hours_complete + allotted_hours_notcomplete_regular + difference_notcomplete_ongoing) AS total
```

I'm basically trying to optimize this query in order to calculate hours for tasks for a given project before merging this to my base `SELECT * FROM projects` query.

1 of these subqueries SELECTS from `tasks` table only, 2 of these select from `tasks` and INNER JOIN on `tasklogs` or vice versa, and 2 of these are simple calculations each other.

Is there a more efficient way of optimizing this? I've never used temporary tables, but maybe I can first select all tasks from `tasks` with the given project id and then do my later SELECTs from that temporary table? Would appreciate any advice.

If needed, I can replicate the schema with a sql fiddle but it would take some time.

Answer (score 1):

You passing from same tables more than once. Without any execution plan, I would try something like following first.

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(GT.tHours) FROM GT
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND t.name LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Placeholder%'
    ) AS allotted_hours_notcomplete_ongoing
    , 
    (SELECT SUM(GT.tlHours) FROM GT
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND t.name LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Placeholder%'
    ) AS logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing
    (SELECT SUM(GT.tlHours) FROM GT
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND t.name LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Placeholder%'
     AND hourtypes_id IN (1,
                          2)) 

    ) AS  logged_hours_complete,
    (SELECT (allotted_hours_notcomplete_ongoing - logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing) + logged_hours_notcomplete_ongoing) AS difference_notcomplete_ongoing,

    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(thours), 0) AS hr
    FROM GT
    WHERE
     AND t.name NOT LIKE '%Ongoing%'
     AND t.name NOT LIKE 'Placeholder%') AS allotted_hours_notcomplete_regular,


    FROM
    (
    SELECT SUM(t.hours) AS tHours ,SUM(tl.hours) AS tlHours, t.name,hourtypes_id
    FROM tasks AS t
    LEFT JOIN tasklogs AS tl ON (tl.tasks_id = t.id)
    WHERE t.projects_id = 8
    AND t.complete != 100
    GROUP BY t.name,hourtypes_id
    ) GT
```

I am basically trying sum hours only once. After that I would filter using inner selects and where. You most certainly need following indexes.

task

```
t.id
t.projects_id
t.complete
t.name
hourtypes_id
t.hours
```

tasklogs

```
tl.tasks_id
tl.hours
```

I assume hourtypes_id is in tasks table.